# Prohibition of meat and fish

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, derabanan, fish

Is the prohibition against consuming meat and fish together considered d’rabbanan, minhag, or some other category? The main reason I ask is because the status of it binding can affect whether one is lenient or machmir.

Comment: It is sakana, which is more stringent than issur. S"A OC 173:2 although the M"A says it is no longer relevant nowadays, most poskim do not agree, see Darchei Teshuva YD 116:16.

Comment: I see. I haven’t seen any real scientific evidence meat and fish are unhealthy together so perhaps some may rely on the Magen Avraham’s heter but proper to be machmir because of tradition?  @Chatzkel

Comment: I do not think chazal sakana are bound by what you have or have not seen based on "real" scientific evidence. Although I recall a question not too long ago asking about what exactly the davar acher is that they refer to and how it fits with current scientific thinking

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114529/why-is-tzaaraas-considered-a-sakana

Comment: @chatzkel "sakana" doesn't answer if it's derabanan or minhag or deorayta. Something actually dangerous is plausibly prohibited deorayta. Something that was once prohibited as dangerous but is not actually dangerous, at least anymore, is either permitted or prohibited as a lasting rabbinic decree or as a retained custom. Fish and meat is unquestionably in the latter group so we have to decide which vestigial aspects of the prohibition, if any, remain binding.

Comment: OP asked if it was ".. or some other category", and sakana is a distinct category. It is always Rabbinic , but the answerer pointed out that that status does not mean can be permissive with it, although one may be so in certain situations (ask your LOR) with Rabbinic requirements. That was the stated point of OP's question, was it not? @DoubleAA

Comment: @Chatzkel Mishna Berurah quotes this Magen Avraham and leaves it at that, seemingly he is ruling like him.

Comment: @EthanLeonard sakana is not a distinct category from those. At best it's a subcategory, but even then it's ill defined. Generally you can be more lenient with rabbinic rules than biblical rules. How easily something is nullified is not always a great way to determine how strict to be with the scope of a prohibition, especially when it isn't nullified for a technical reason.